# Fazer ul se mover usando apenas script

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5, css3

Olá!

Eu vi um exemplo de carrossel que usar o recurso de **margin** para simular o movimento dos itens.

Como eu posso apenas com o script, fazer algo parecido, considerando que o código repete a estrutura?

Eu imagino que se eu colocar um **evento de "passar"** no botão de passar... ele vai movimentar todos os carrosséis.
Como seria nesse caso, para fazer com que ele passe os itens de maçã, sem interferir nos outros?

```css
* {list-style:none}
.cesta-de-frutas {
  padding:5px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lista-de-frutas {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  float: none;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.lista-de-frutas > ul {

    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.lista-de-frutas > ul li {

    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-top: 5px;}

.controle {

    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;

}
.voltar {

    margin-right: 30px;

}
```

```html
<div class="recipiente">
    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="cesta-de-frutas">
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Banana tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Uva tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Fiz algumas modificações no seu código e adicionei um script que acredito que faz o que você quer. Eu não usei a ideia de `margin` que você citou, eu fiz usando uma classe `active` para mostrar/esconder um item.

Segue o código:

```js
var listasDeFrutas = document.querySelectorAll('.lista-de-frutas');


for (var i = 0; i < listasDeFrutas.length; i++){
  criarCarrossel(listasDeFrutas[i]);
}

function criarCarrossel(listaDeFrutas){
  var lis = listaDeFrutas.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
  var passar = listaDeFrutas.parentNode.querySelector('.passar');
  var voltar = listaDeFrutas.parentNode.querySelector('.voltar');
  var atual = 0;
  
  passar.onclick = function(){
    atual = ++atual % lis.length;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
      lis[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    
    lis[atual].classList.add('active');
  }
  
  voltar.onclick = function(){
    atual--;
    if ( atual < 0 ) atual = lis.length - 1;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
      lis[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    lis[atual].classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
* {list-style:none}
.cesta-de-frutas {
  padding:5px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lista-de-frutas {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  float: none;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.lista-de-frutas > ul {
   display: flex;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

.lista-de-frutas > ul li {
   display: none;
   margin-right: 80px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.lista-de-frutas > ul li.active {
   display: block;
}

.controle {
   display: flex;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   justify-content: center;
   color: white;
}

.voltar, .passar {
   cursor: pointer;
}

.voltar {
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipiente">
    <div class="conteiner">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="cesta-de-frutas">
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active">Maçã tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Maçã tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active">Banana tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Banana tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active">Abacate tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Abacate tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                    <div class="lista-de-frutas">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active">Uva tipo 1</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 2</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 3</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 4</li>
                            <li>Uva tipo 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="controle">
                        <li class="voltar"> voltar </li>
                        <li class="passar"> passar </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá! Muito obrigado pela resposta!

O parentNode vai pegar apenas os elementos daquele conjunto armazenado pelo querySelectorAll. É isso?

Sendo assim, se eu usar a variável que armazena o querySelectorAll com o parentNode... eu só irei selecionar o <li>, por exemplo, daquele index que eu informei.

É assim?

Comment: Não sei entendi sua pergunta. O `parentNode` pega o elemento _pai_ de outro elemento na árvore do html. No caso, usei para pegar o `li` que contém a lista de frutas e o controle de cada carrossel. Note que na primeira linha eu seleciono todas as listas de frutas, mas dentro da função `criarCarrossel` eu utilizo apenas a lista que foi passada como parâmetro. O `querySelector` faz uma busca dentro de um elemento. Estou usando para buscar dentro do `li` devolvido com `parentNode` os elementos com classe `passar` e `voltar`.

Comment: Certo!
Não estou conseguindo aplicar bem ao meu caso real mas acredito que o problema sou eu. rsrs
De qualquer forma você me mostrou o caminho das pedras. Vou estudar sobre esse código que você mandou pra ver se consigo aplicar ao meu caso.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda e até mais!